# Order of dynamic and static routes in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a blog frontend with React and I have a couple static routes (home and videos) and the rest of the site is covered by a dynamic route that pulls the page content from the api. I am trying to figure out the best way to cover the static routes which are always being caught by the dynamic route. The home page works fine but the videos route is always being caught by the dynamic route.

I have this as my Router

```
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0,0)} history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Layout>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
            <Route exact path="/videos" render={() => <Videos />} />
            <Route path="/:url" render={() => <Post />} />
        </Layout>

      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

I was thinking that the static routes first (and with exact) will catch and show the correct component before it hits the dynamic route...which isn't the case.

Any ideas on how to be able to catch a static routes first if they match and not the dynamic route?

Thanks and let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I needed to move the Layout component outside the Switch to get the routes to work as needed.